# Check whether a C++ pure virtual function has been defined in derived class

Tags: c++

I created (long time ago) a library (dll) from a base class with pure virtual functions. This library works fine. Now I added more pure virtual functions to the base class and create a new library. This works fine too. But if I load the old library into my new applications that expect the new added functions, my program crashes. Of course because the programm tries to have access to the pure virtual functions that are not exists in the old library.

How can I detect, if the new virtual functions were defined in the library e.g. check for NULL pointer of the function?

Comment: Just call the new class something else.

Comment: @Tobi Add some kind of versioning to your libraries.

Comment: Is there no way to check if the function is existing?